# Discord.py error : object NoneType can't be used in "await" expression when trying to make the bot leave a voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm currently trying to code a **discord bot in python** and am trying to make it join a channel, play a sound and then leave.

I came up with this code :

```
@bot.command()
async def sound(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await join(ctx)
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('sound.mp3')
    await voice.play(source)
    await channel.disconnect()
```

However, when I try it, after playing the sound, it doesn't disconnect and there is in my shell an error :

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
>   exception: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await'
>   expression

I saw on forums that it could be a asyncio problem but I don't know how to resolve it.

Could someone help me please ?

Edit : my imports on my program :

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
```

Edit v2 : the join() command :

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a vocal channel.")
        return
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    elif voice == channel:
        return
    else:
        await channel.connect()
```

Comment: Please update your question to include all code needed to run this. For example, you have `await join(ctx)` but not what `join` does since it's not included. This is just a guess, but try `await voice.disconnet()`

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for your time. I edited my post with the join() fonction at the bottom. I also tried to run my code with voice.disconnect() but I ended having the same error message

Comment: Does it also show on what line the error occured?

Comment: The error was at the "await channel.disconnect()" line

Answer (score 3):

You can have your `join` command return the [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient) object and use it directly to play the sound instead of using `discord.utils.get`. You can also get the `VoiceClient` object directly from the `bot.voice_clients` list instead of using `get` when checking if the bot is connected to a voice channel already.

Note that `voice.play` does not need `await` as it is not a coroutine. You also need to check if the bot stops playing audio using `while voice.is_playing()` before disconnecting, otherwise it will disconnect immediately after starting to play the sound.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')


@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    voice = None
    for vc in bot.voice_clients:
        if vc.guild == ctx.guild:
            voice = vc

    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a vocal channel.")
        return
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        vc = await voice.move_to(channel)
    elif voice == channel:
        return
    else:
        vc = await channel.connect()
    return vc


@bot.command()
async def sound(ctx):
    voice = await join(ctx)
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('sound.m4a')
    voice.play(source)
    while voice.is_playing():
        continue
    await voice.disconnect()

bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
while voice.is_playing():
        continue
    await voice.disconnect()
```

will mess up the audio.

Do this instead:

```
while voice.is_playing():
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This will freeze the bot! Use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` instead